# How to achieve automatic authentication using GCE Go client oauth2 authentication

Tags: go, sdk, google-compute-engine

This code is on the basis of golang.org/x/oauth2 example test. I am trying to get instance information from Google Compute Engine using Go client. Do I have to use oauth2 authentication? There is a generated link after `Visit the URL for the auth dialog`:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcompute&response_type=code&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcompute&state=state

and it redirect to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute which shows a 'compute'.
How do I achieve automatic authentication?

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
    "google.golang.org/api/compute/v1"
)

type GCE struct {
    *compute.Service
}

var ctx = context.Background()

func initGCE() *GCE {
    conf := &oauth2.Config{
        ClientID:     "xxx",
        ClientSecret: "xxx",
        Scopes:       []string{compute.ComputeScope},
        Endpoint: oauth2.Endpoint{
            AuthURL:  "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
            TokenURL: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        },
        RedirectURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute",

    }
    url := conf.AuthCodeURL("state", oauth2.AccessTypeOffline)
    fmt.Printf("Visit the URL for the auth dialog: %v", url)
    var code string
    if _, err := fmt.Scan(&code); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    tok, err := conf.Exchange(ctx, code)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    service, err := compute.New(conf.Client(ctx, tok))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return &GCE{service}
}

func (g *GCE) Instance() {
    project := "arctic-cyclist-189707"
    zone := "us-east1-b"
    instance := "centos7"
    resp, err := g.Instances.Get(project, zone, instance).Context(ctx).Do()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", resp)

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about the example in the [oauth docs](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2#example-Config)? If so, you can scroll up about 15 lines and see that `Config` has a `RedirectURL string` field. If you are talking about something else, please link to it.

Comment: Yes, I wonder what RedirectURL should be, because I don't quite understand this authentication flow.

Comment: I still don't know what you're asking. Redirect URI is the url of your application. After authentication with the oauth server, the user will be redirected to your application with an access token.

Comment: What should RedirectURL be in a localhost test and where do I get the authentication code, and scan mean a manual interact , shouldn't this flow be automatic? I am trying to get instance information from GCE.

Comment: There are a lot of [tutorials](https://jacobmartins.com/2016/02/29/getting-started-with-oauth2-in-go/) available out there. Please read it thoroughly to 1) understand how oauth works and 2) how to use it inside your app. And yes, there's manual involvement. You're asking people to authenticate, they need to be able to provide permission and optionally specify which account to authenticate with.

Comment: My target is compute engine other than an app. Automatic authenticate can be achieved by GCE javascript client
 function authorization() {
       gapi.client.setApiKey(API_KEY);
       gapi.auth.authorize({
         client_id: CLIENT_ID,
         scope: SCOPES,
         immediate: true
       }, function(authResult) {
            if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
              initializeApi();
            } else {
              window.alert('Auth was not successful');
            }
          }
       );
     }

Comment: Oh,  now I see. Oauth is to authenticate users. If you want to use the google cloud sdk within an instance, you should use [service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using code example

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/get#examples

just set "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" environment varibles as google.DefaultClient() requires.
package main

```
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
    "google.golang.org/api/compute/v1"
)

type GCE struct {
    *compute.Service
}

var ctx = context.Background()

func initGCE() *GCE {
    c, err := google.DefaultClient(ctx, compute.CloudPlatformScope)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    computeService, err := compute.New(c)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return &GCE{computeService}
}

func (g *GCE) Instance(project, zone, instance string) {
    resp, err := g.Instances.Get(project, zone, instance).Context(ctx).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", resp)
}
```

Thanks for your reply.